# iOS app crashes while converting multiple images to base64

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, base64

The app has a feature of capturing multiple photos and uploading it to the server. When I loop through 100 images and convert it to base64, it works fine. But if I increase the number of images then it crashes, it doesn't go in the catch block. Below is the code snippet:

```
List<UIImage> capturedImage= new List<UIImage>();
foreach (var photo in capturedImage) {  
    var photoImage = photo; 
    using (NSData imgData = photoImage.AsJPEG(0.5f)) {
        var strinng = imgData.GetBase64EncodedString(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None);
        imageBase64.Add(strinng);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its Xamarin iOS.

Comment: Added tag of that!

Comment: Your app might crash due to out of memory. Check if you are getting any memory warning.

Comment: I have overridden ReceiveMemoryWarning method in app delegate file `public override void ReceiveMemoryWarning(UIApplication application)
{
 base.ReceiveMemoryWarning(application);
}` But its never getting called.

Comment: @Arti Monitor the device logs for details of the crash, also you need to be disposing of those NSData instances, but in general I would *assume* it is an an memory allocation failure due to fragmentation, but I do not know the size of those UIImages, but 100 or more in an LIST and existing a base64 at the same time? That is a recipe for fragmentation failure.